# What is the shortest way to add redux to react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm integrating `redux` to my react-native application. Want to introduce `Provider` and to wrap screens in it. I'm using such constructions to register new screen:

```
Navigation.registerComponent('Login', () => LoginScreen);
```

As I see in [documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/api/component/) I need to wrap every component in `<Provider store={store}>`

And I'm just wondering if exist another way to do this, because if I have 10 screens(for example) in my app, I need to wrap them in provider ten times. I'll get code duplicates, but htis is not good

Comment: Place the Provider component into the App.js at the top level and then you can add the NavigationContainer.

Comment: @DánielBoros didn't quite understand your idea

Comment: Do you want to store the screen data in the redux store or do you want to access the data on all screens?

Comment: @DánielBoros I want to create universal application context-like(using redux store) and access it from screens\components. so from any screen I want to access state

Comment: You can do something like that: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3549#issuecomment-407553700, but I think that https://reactnavigation.org/ and https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens much better choice for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating an AppContainer component with all the components and wrap the AppContainer component inside the Provider.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { Provider as StoreProvider } from "react-redux";

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
 firstcomponentpath: FirstComponent,
 secondcomponentpath: SecondComponent
)}

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {
super(props);
this.state = {};
}

render() {
return (
<Provider store={store}>
<AppConatiner />
</Provider>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to directly add `navigation` to your store at the init :

HomePage.tsx

```
interface HomePageProps {
  navigation: {
    navigate: (pathName: string) => void;
  };
}
```

```
const HomePage: FunctionComponent<HomePageProps> = (props) => {
    const { navigation } = props;
    initStore(navigation);
```

Store.ts

```
export const fetchInitStore = (props: HomePageProps) => {
  const { navigation } = props;

  const action: Actions = {
    type: ActionType.INIT_STORE_STATE,
    payload: {
      Navigation: navigation,
    },
  };
  return action;
};

export const initStore = (props: HomePageProps) => {
  (store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<State, unknown, Actions>)(fetchInitStore(props));
};
```

In you reducer :

```
case ActionType.INIT_STORE_STATE:
  return actions.payload;
```

Then you can use it in other cases :

`state.Navigation.navigation.navigate('Login');`